# add many2one field in inherited view

Tags: odoo-8

I want to display my Many2one field.
I inherited from the `hr_timesheet_sheet.sheet` model like this:

```
class list_activity_sheet(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'hr_timesheet_sheet.sheet'
    activity_id = fields.Many2one('list_activity_sheet.activity')

class List_activity(models.Model):
    _name='list_activity_sheet.activity'
    name= fields.Char('Description',required=True)
```

And for the View:

```
<openerp>
<data>
    <record id="List_activity_form" model="ir.ui.view">
                <field name="name">hr_timesheet_sheet.sheet.form.inherit</field>
                <field name="model">hr_timesheet_sheet.sheet</field>
                <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr_timesheet_sheet.hr_timesheet_sheet_form"/>
                <field name="arch" type="xml">
                    <xpath expr="/form/sheet/notebook/page[@string='Details']/field/tree/field[@name='name']" position="after">
                        <field name="activity_id"></field>
                    </xpath>

                </field>
     </record>
</data>
```

When i install my addon , i got that message:
`field activity_id doesn't exist in the view`.

Does anyone know how to solve that?

Comment: Is your python file imported in ```__init__.py``` ?

Comment: Yes. Because when i use a simple  field's type like Char, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're working on the wrong model. If i understand your view definition correctly, you want to choose an activity on the sheet lines.

You have to inherit `hr.analytic.timesheet` for that instead of `hr_timesheet_sheet.sheet`. In Odoo 9+ you have to inherit `account.analytic.line`, because `hr.analytic.timesheet` was kicked out.

Comment: Thank you very much @CZoellner. Indeed i inherited from the wrong model